# отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция strstr

Tags: c++, c

Собстна проблемка)

**Изначальный код на "С"**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>

BOOL APIENTRY DllEntryPoint(HMODULE hModule, DWORD dwReasonForCall, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    if (dwReasonForCall == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {
        DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hModule);
        TCHAR* cmdline = GetCommandLine();
        if (StrStr(cmdline, "-one") || StrStr(cmdline, "-one1") || StrStr(cmdline, "-one2")) {
            LoadLibrary("client.dll");
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

**Переписал на "С++"** *(*хоть и разница не большая*)*

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>



BOOL APIENTRY DllEntryPoint(HMODULE hModule, DWORD dwReasonForCall, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    if (dwReasonForCall == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {
        DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hModule);
        TCHAR* cmdline = GetCommandLine();
        if (strstr(cmdline, "-one") || strstr(cmdline, "-one1") || strstr(cmdline, "-one2")) {
            LoadLibrary("client.dll");
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

**И получил ошибки**

```
E0304   отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция "strstr", соответствующие списку аргументов
E0304   отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция "strstr", соответствующие списку аргументов
E0304   отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция "strstr", соответствующие списку аргументов
E0167   аргумент типа "const char *" несовместим с параметром типа "LPCWSTR"
```

***Нигде так и не нашёл подробный разбор решения данных ошибок, прошу Вашей помощи!***

Comment: В `strstr` передаются аргументы разных типов. А должны быть одного. Как иначе она будет подстроки искать?

Comment: Так как должна называться функция`StrStr` или `strstr`?  Стандартная `strstr` определена в `<cstring>`: `const char* strstr( const char* str, const char* target );`

Comment: @Borls Судя из ошибки в переменной cmdline хранится не const shar *. Потому функция strstr и ругается.

Comment: Можете подсказать, как правильно сделать?

Comment: Важно не то, что вы переписали на С++, а то, что, судя по `LPCWSTR` в описании ошибки — см. **`W`** — работаете с Unicode и широкими символами. А как правильно? зависит от того, собираетесь ли вы работать с Unicode и `wchar_t`, или это произошло случайно...